# How to get CountyId or StateId in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, leaflet

I want to get countyId in Leaflet

```
info.update = function (props) {
        if (props) {
            propsState = props.State;  //StateName
            propsName = props.name;    //CountyName
            propsRanking = props.Ranking;
        }
    };
```

Above code only get StateName and CountyName. How can i get CountyId or StateId?

Comment: Are you following a tutorial from somewhere?  Where is the `info` object coming from?

Comment: im following the http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html, but i dont see their get countyid

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the ID number is one level up from the properties sub-object.  The GeoJSON is laid out like this:

```
var statesData = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "01",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Alabama",
            "density": 94.65
        },
        "geometry": { 
           //continues on for a long time...
```

The code in the `highlightFeature function`, which is the code that is run on MouseOver, passes in the object `layer.feature.properties`.  This then becomes the `props` in your function.  Which if you look at the GeoJSON, is one level down from the ID value.

To fix this, pass in `layer.feature` instead, and change your function to the below:

```
info.update = function (feature) {
    if (feature) {
      var props = feature.properties;
      propsState = props.State;  //StateName
      propsName = props.name;    //CountyName
      propsID = feature.id;  //NOTE we are using feature here, NOT props
      propsRanking = props.Ranking;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks you. May be this code is working for State, but my problem that get **county** and  The GeoJSON is laid out like this:<br/>
`var counties = [
{"type":"Feature","id":"01001","properties":{"name":"Autauga","Ranking":5,"State":"Alabama"},"geometry"....`<br/>
The **ID number of county** is same level with **properties**

Comment: And I'm following try your code but it doesn't work, and I retrieve the error at **var props = feature.properties;** position with the error: **0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'properties' of undefined or null reference**

Comment: Sorry.  On first run it doesn't pass in any feature which is why you get the null reference.  Just do a quick check for feature `if (feature) { var props = feature.properties; } //continue on` Here's a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vnBAK/) showing this.  I also edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: yes, it's work. Thank you help
And the new problem does it run not ok in Firefox browser (it's run very very slowly), but it runs ok in Chrome? You can see my demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TienKenji/VnhbA/7/)

Comment: I don't know.  Maybe a Leaflet problem.  I'd ask another question.